# Search many-to-many relationships that match the exact conditions in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to implement a chatroom backend in Rails where I have `User` and `ChatRoom` models that `has_many` each other through a `ChatRoomSubscription` model. I am trying to find a way to implement a messages system (kinda like Messages app on iOS) where the user can enter one or more user IDs that they want to chat with and the backend will look for a chatroom that has those exact users (or create one if that doesn't exist). I want to write a query that:

> Search `ChatRoomSubscription` model and return the `ChatRoom` ID where its corresponding `User`s ***exactly*** match a given list

How would I go about doing in Rails? Or just SQL query for that matter?